# How to create controller class instance to pass it as argument of 'Test.invokeContinuationMethod' while Callback method is Static

Tags: continuation

**Background**:

VF remoting (@remoteAction) is being used to fetch data - this method is declared as Static (in order to make it available for @remoteAction). In this method, in order to make long running callout to external server, we are using [Continuation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_overview.htm) as described here which makes a callback to another method which is again marked as Static (because it's being called from Static).

```
global class CalloutController{
    @RemoteAction
    public static Object helpSupportAgents(String body){
      ..
      Continuation searchContinuation = new Continuation(120); 
      searchContinuation.continuationMethod = 'callbackMethod';
      ....
    }
    public static Object callbackMethod(Object state){
      ...    
      ....
    }

}
```

**Problem**

While writing [test code for Continuation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_testing.htm), we need to use below given methods of System.Test class which requires an instance of class/controller as argument. Presumably this object must be calling given callback method mentioned in Continuation instantiation and throwing error.

> System.TypeException: No method 'callbackMethod()' on provided
>   controller type.

```
CalloutController controller = new CalloutController();
Test.setContinuationResponse(CalloutController.requestLabel, response);
Object result = Test.invokeContinuationMethod(controller, conti);
```

It's obvious that error is because we can not call Static method by object of Class. Then I tried using *.class* as we do for interface but it does not work as well.

```
Test.setContinuationResponse(CalloutController.requestLabel, response);
Object result = Test.invokeContinuationMethod(CalloutController.class, conti);
```

**Now, I'm not able to find any doc or any way to pass static class reference as argument**. Any suggestion or experience?
Similar issue reported here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005oLoQAI

**P.S:** For just sake of deployment, I've called both methods separately in test class and good in terms of code coverage but still want to know best way to solve it.

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided more of your code. It doesn't seem to me as though there's quite enough to duplicate the exact issue you're experiencing.

Comment: There are lot of unreleated code...so I just added code related to continuation already above ...but still if you need that code I can add but..i dont think it's gonna help.....as issue pertains to test class....

Comment: Here is source code: https://github.com/ayub-ansari/Continuation

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a gap in the testing framework for continuations. The problem is not that your method is static, but that the callback method does not match the method signature expected by Salesforce, which has 0 arguments.

I ended up making my methods testable with the following structure, which puts the logic into a 0 argument method, but then allows my remote action to use it by storing the state in a static variable. I hate adjusting my code to make it testable, but sometimes it seems like the only way in Salesforce. This does unfortunately leave the first method untested within the continuation flow but I couldn't find a better way, I'm not saying this is the best way to solve it!

```
global with sharing class ContinuationController {
    @TestVisible
    private static String currentState;

    global static Object callback(Object state) {
        currentState = (String)state;
        return callback();
    }

    global static Object callback() {
        HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(currentState);
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Test method:

```
@IsTest
static void testContinuation() {

    // Invoke the continuation by calling the action method
    Continuation con = (Continuation)ContinuationController.makeCallout();

    // Verify that the continuation has the proper requests
    Map<String, HttpRequest> requests = con.getRequests();

    System.assertEquals(1, requests.size());

    // create mock response
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    //set body, status code etc.

    Test.setContinuationResponse(ContinuationController.currentState, response);

    // Invoke callback method
    Object result = Test.invokeContinuationMethod(new ContinuationController(), con);
}
```

If you have access to Salesforce support then I'd suggest logging a case and see what they say.

Comment: Should I log an Idea or log a case with Salesforce?

Comment: On second thoughts, the case might not get very far, and I suspect an idea would struggle to get enough votes to get Salesforce to look at it, but I'd vote for it - up to you! :). I've also submitted a documentation bug on this page https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_testing.htm to ask them to explain how to test a static continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to cover some parts of the code, you can pass the processResponse() in the argument just like this:

```
    try{
    Object result = Test.invokeContinuationMethod(ContinuationSampleCode.processResponse(new List<String>{ContinuationSampleCode.requestLabel}, testObj), conti);
    }

Catch(Exception exc){
    //any statement
}
```

Here 'testObj' is any dummy/actual object/wrapper/inner class from your ContinuationSampleCode class. It will thrown an error which will be caught in catch block.